# pip install gives TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: debian, package-management, pip

I have seen this error in other sites and in here as well, but the solutions provided are not fixing it. **Operating System: Mendel GNU/Linux 5 (Eagle)** (debian). When trying to install `psutil`, I am getting an error:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade psutil
Collecting psutil
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 338, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 218, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 164, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 572, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 534, in find_all_candidates
    self._package_versions(page.iter_links(), search)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 702, in _package_versions
    v = self._link_package_versions(link, search)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 777, in _link_package_versions
    support_this_python = check_requires_python(link.requires_python)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/packaging.py", line 33, in check_requires_python
    return python_version in requires_python_specifier
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/packaging-19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/packaging/specifiers.py", line 676, in __contains__
    return self.contains(item)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/packaging-19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/packaging/specifiers.py", line 681, in contains
    item = parse(item)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/packaging-19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/packaging/version.py", line 28, in parse
    return Version(version)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/packaging-19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/packaging/version.py", line 219, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I could not find the file `/usr/share/python-wheels/packaging-19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/packaging/version.py` (as there was nothing after the `.whl` file but my guess was that `packaging-19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` is a wheel that depended on `pip3`. So I searched for `version.py` in my system.

```
$ sudo find / -name version.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debianbts/version.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/version.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/chardet/version.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/version.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/ma/version.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenGL/version.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_vendor/packaging/version.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/version.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/version.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/version.py
/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/version.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pydantic/version.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/websockets/version.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_cors/version.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/packaging/version.py
/usr/share/python3/debpython/version.py
/usr/share/dh-python/dhpython/version.py
/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py
```

I edited both files that have `packaging/version.py`, which are:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/packaging/version.py
```

This did not affect the output of the pip3 install, the change was:
`match = self._regex.search(version)` to `match = self._regex.search(str(version))`

I then proceeded to change the other files that had `/packaging/version.py`

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/version.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_vendor/packaging/version.py
```

But nothing is changing. I've seen that it might be a problem of the [wheel in debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206121/pip-install-gives-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable) (the error is not exactly the same, but downgrading the wheel seems kind of okay?), but I am not sure nor do I know how much can this screw my system (I've had package manager problems before and had to delete my linux distribution, so I want to be careful).

EDIT: pip3 version:

```
$ pip3 --version
    pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

EDIT: This problem arose when trying to install [PyAccessPoint](https://pypi.org/project/PyAccessPoint/). For some reason, installing it **the hard way**, worked, but still doesn't fix this issue nor future issues with the wheel:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt --yes --force-yes install dnsmasq hostapd python3-dev unzip python3-pip && cd ~ && wget --output-document=pyaccesspoint-master.zip https://github.com/Goblenus/pyaccesspoint/archive/master.zip && unzip pyaccesspoint-master.zip && cd pyaccesspoint-master && sudo python3 setup.py install && cd ~ && sudo rm -rf pyaccesspoint-master.zip pyaccesspoint-master
```